# How to perform Network calls in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application just like the Photos app from Apple. Before I initialise the UITableViewController, I make a network call to the server asking for the first 100 picture URLs.

Using these URLs, I can prefetch the images from the server and display them in the UITableView. However, oftentimes I have 10000's of pictures that the user could scroll through. I'm wondering how to keep track of the users location in de UITableView and when to ask the server for a new list of picture urls.

More specifically, I'm wondering if there exists a 'standard' approach that Photos also uses in conjunction with iCloud.

Comment: The table delegate tells you when the user scrolls and when a cell is displayed/ends being displayed.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching

Comment: But how do you know if you're nearly at the end of your URL list and have to make a new call. Do you give each cell a digit? E.g. 1, 2,..

Comment: You use the indexPath. I'm sorry. Should've known

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply Use scrollView Delegate, tableview is byDefault inherited from UIScrollView

```
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if self.tableView.contentOffset.y <= -10  {

        // table view reached top place your pull to refresh call here
    } else if ((tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.frame.size.height) >= tableView.contentSize.height) {
        //table view reached last record, fetch next records here
   }
}
```

and don't forget to inherit controller from UIScrollViewDelegate.

Comment: also do not forget to set the delegate